# Supplementing User Profile with information from BCS

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, user-profile-service, synchronisation

I've got my external content type and BCS all sorted and working - the list view of the external list shows 100% in the site and the external content type shows under my BCS service application.

Now I want to create a connection to this in my user profile synchronisation in order to map some additional info from this list to my user profiles (if possible using the email field as the 1-on-1 identifier). As soon as I try to do this I either get "External Content Types are not available" if I try to see what ECTs are available when adding the new synchronisation connection or the drop down for "Return items identified by this profile property" is empty if I manually enter the ECT name (and when I do the latter it finds the ECT)

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set correct permissions for both BCS and UPA (both connection and administrative permissions)

Comment: Hi Anders, The connection account is the same for both and the administator for the service apps is the same on them all (ie myself).

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to figure out.  Not sure if it's the same situation.  For me, it was one particular DB causing the issue.  Turns out the identifier in my ECT was a system.guid which sharepoint has shortcomings in.  I had to change the identifier to a different field in my ECt.

Answer (score 0):

Please drive through the whole process again and make sure to check whether your ECT has set object permissions "Execute" and "set permissions" in the Business Data Connectivity services service application.

Comment: This would make a better comment than an answer. Please make comments comments and answers answers in the future, this can affect the question openers acceptance score.